# DataGridView sorts dates in wrong order

Tags: sql, winforms, date, datagridview

I have a DataGridView and a searchbox where I can search for different dates in a certain column. Now since the date is formated as string he will give me the wrong order:

I type in 20 and get:

20.10.2014,
22.09.2014,
24.11.2014

and so on. I have read another thread here about this problem but the solutions didn't help me. My SQL statement looks like following:

```
 DataTable datTable = new DataTable();

 sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ["+form1.timeBox.Text+ "] FROM [" + form1.getTableName() + "] WHERE convert(varchar(10),[" + form1.getTimeCol() + "],104) >= '" + form1.getFromDate().Trim() + "' ORDER BY convert(varchar(10),[" + form1.getTimeCol() + "],104) ASC", connection);

   sqlDatAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd.CommandText, connection);

            sqlDatAdapter.Fill(datTable);

            form1.setDataGrid = datTable;
```

and

```
form1.getFromDate()
```

is the function which grabs the entered string from the Textbox to search for. I tried to cast and convert to datetime and so on but it gets still shown in the wrong order. Can anyone help?

Comment: what's the data type of the column you are using to order your result set? please post some raw data.

Comment: The datatype of the column is "date". To search for it I convert it to varchar (see above). But how to let him display the dates in the right order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are ordering by the formatted column; there is no need to do so and that is the part creating your problem.

i'm against string concatenation to build sql commands but your code should be rewritten as follows:

```
sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ["+form1.timeBox.Text+ "] FROM [" + form1.getTableName() + "] WHERE convert(varchar(10),[" + form1.getTimeCol() + "],104) >= '" + form1.getFromDate().Trim() + "' ORDER BY " + form1.getTimeCol() + " ASC", connection);
```

Comment: Wow! That seems to help. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

nstead of using '>=' use 'Like' operator with '%' character at the end of your "form1.getFromDate().Trim()", which will give you the required result.

Using 'Like' your query will look like:

```
sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ["+form1.timeBox.Text+ "] FROM [" + form1.getTableName() + "] WHERE convert(varchar(10),[" + form1.getTimeCol() + "],104) Like '" + form1.getFromDate().Trim() + "%' ORDER BY convert(varchar(10),[" + form1.getTimeCol() + "],104) ASC", connection);
```

Comment: I would use LIKE when I would search for a concrete date. I have to Textboxes "from" and "till" so I have to set a range

Comment: Now I came up with the same answer as of Paolo, after creating sample table.